# Diagonal embedding into finite idele group

Tags: number-theory, local-field

Recall that one has the equality $\mathbb{A}_f^{\times}=\mathbb{A}^{\times}_{\mathbb{Q},f}=\mathbb{Q}^{\times}.\prod\limits_{p<\infty}\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, so I would like to know if its generalization to arbitrary number field still holds, i.e. let $k$ be a number field, then is it true that $\mathbb{A}^{\times}_{k,f}=k^{\times}.\prod\limits_{v<\infty}\mathcal{O}_v^{\times}$? Here we identify $k^{\times}$ with its image of diagonal embedding in $\mathbb{A}^{\times}_{k,f}$.

Thanks very much!

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^{\times}_{k,f}=\mathcal{I}_k \prod\limits_{v<\infty}\mathcal{O}_v^{\times}$  where $\mathcal{I}_k$ are the fractional ideals of $k$. But there is a [finite subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring#Theorem:_characterisation_of_the_idele_group) $S$ of primes such that $\mathbb{A}^{\times}_{k}=k^\times \prod\limits_{v \in S}k_v^{\times} \prod\limits_{v \not \in S}\mathcal{O}_v^{\times}= k^\times  \  \prod_{v \in S} \varpi_v^\mathbb{Z} \ \prod\limits_{v}\mathcal{O}_v^{\times}$ thanks to the finiteness of the class group